# como adicionar uma simple polylines ao Mapa Api gmaps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Nao consigo visualizar a linha no mapa o codigo aparentemente está correto nao quebra em nenhuma linha ,quando visualizo pelo console .mais nao visualiza a linha.

```
 function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes, longitudes);

        var options = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        if (coord.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
                var location = coord[i].split(",");

                pontos[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]);

            }

            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: pontos,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                map: map,
            });

            flightPath.setMap(map);
        }
    }

    initialize();
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: Não consigo visualizar no mapa a linha!

Comment: Explique sua dúvida mais detalhadamente no corpo da pergunta

Comment: Seu *array* `pontos` foi definido e inicializado?

Comment: sim declarei o array dentro da funcao até

Comment: Tentei reproduzir exatamente o que você tem aqui no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pauloandre/hqpbrxff/) e funcionou corretamente. Veja se consegue comparar com o que você tem.

Comment: existe limites de pontos?pois meu array de pontos eh uma lista bem extensa!

Comment: Acredito que não exista nenhum limite. Você experimentou fazer este teste com um número reduzido?

Comment: fiz um teste ate com um array ja definido com alguns itens. e mesmo assim nao gera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pontos,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            map: map
        });
```

Você não precisa da vírgula no último parâmetro.

```
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
```

A `div` de seu mapa realmente se chama "mapa", se você a nomeou assim ok, mas muitas vezes está "map-canvas" ou "map", como nos exemplo, se você mudou ok!

Acredito que seja apenas a vírgula no final dos parametros do **flightPath**.

Comment: Eu fiz alguns testes e acho que tem limites de coordenadas para fazer a Polyline, só consigo desenha-la com 8 coordenadas se passar disso não mostra nada!

Comment: acho que nao existe limites, pois desenho polyline de rastreamento com varias coordenadas, olha... 

`var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                geodesic: true,
                                strokeColor: '#0000FF',
                                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                strokeWeight: 2,
                                map: map
                            });`
ai depois eu adiciono os pontos...

`flightPath.getPath().push(linha[i]);`

a linha é um array de LatLng

Comment: Alem da Polyline posso visualizar ao mesmo tempo o marcador no mapa?

Comment: Sim @HansMiller, utilizo essa função `setInterval(function () {
                                clearMarkers();//limpo os marker
                                linha[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                                flightPath.getPath().push(linha[i]); //cria a linha
                                i++;
addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));// adiciono novamente o marker na nova posição}, 1000);`
esta function executa a cada 1000 ms, e o marker vai ficar na ultima posição da linha [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_PCvjVwHww]